# Grails: unexpected token in groovy file

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working on a small project (Grails) and I am trying to use this import statement:

```
<%=packageName ? "import ${packageName}.${className}" : ''%>
```

but as it seems every time I put this into one of my Groovy classes I get the following error:

```
Groovy:unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
```

Does anyone know why this occurs?
Also this is a small snippet of the code:

```
<%=packageName ? "import ${packageName}.${className}" : ''%> 

import groovy.lang.Script

class ${className}Controller {

def index = { redirect(action:list,params:params) }
def allowedMethods = [delete:'POST', save:'POST', update:'POST']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a template file.  They are found in `src/templates` and are used to generate actual controllers with `grails generate-controller` or `grails create-controller`.  The actual application controllers in `grails-app/controllers` shouldn't have embedded expressions like `<%=packageName ? "import ${packageName}.${className}" : ''%>` or `${className}`.